# Changes made to a string array in a function are all lost when function ends and program goes back to main function even though it is using pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers

I declared these variables inside main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE* dictionaryFP;
    FILE* hashedDictionaryFP;
    int i, noOfWords, arrayLength, choice;
    char** dictionary;
    ...
}
```

Here's the function that reads words from a .txt file and saves them all to string array called dictionary.

```
void readHashedDictionary (FILE* hashedDictionaryFP, char** dictionary, int arrayLength){
    char word[WORD_LENGTH];
    int index;
    dictionary = (char**) malloc ((arrayLength) * sizeof(char*));
    while (fscanf(hashedDictionaryFP, "%d: %s\n", &index, word) > 0){
        dictionary[index] = (char*) malloc (WORD_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(dictionary[index], word);
        printf("%d: %s\n", index, dictionary[index]);
    }
    printf("TEST: %s", dictionary[7740]);
}
```

I checked a random word to see if function functions properly and it did. It displayed the word on the 7740. node of the string array.

However, in the main function, I can't access any word of the string array. The output of the code below is: "(null)".

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...
    hashedDictionaryFP = fopen("hashedDictionary.txt", "r");
    if (hashedDictionaryFP == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    fscanf(hashedDictionaryFP, "%d\n", &arrayLength);
    dictionary = (char**) malloc (arrayLength * (sizeof(char*)));
    readHashedDictionary(hashedDictionaryFP, dictionary, arrayLength);
    displayHashedDictionary(dictionary, arrayLength);
    printf("%s", dictionary[7740]);
    printf("LOL");
    return 0;
}
```

Since I'm working with pointers here (char**) I thought changes made to the string array wouldn't be gone when we go back to the main function. What is wrong with my code?

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORD_LENGTH 30

int countWords (FILE*);
int calculateArrayLength (int);
void fixCapitalLetters (char*);
int hash (char**, char*, int);
void readDictionary (FILE*, char**, int);
void printHashedDictionary (FILE*, char**, int);
void readHashedDictionary(FILE*, char**, int);
void displayHashedDictionary(char**, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE* dictionaryFP;
    FILE* hashedDictionaryFP;
    int i, noOfWords, arrayLength, choice;
    char** dictionary;

    printf("Daha once kelimeleri hash'leyip hashedDictionary.txt dosyasini olusturduysaniz 0 sayisini giriniz.\n");
    printf("hashedDicionary.txt dosyasi hazir degilse hazirlamak icin herhangi bir sayi giriniz.\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    if (choice != 0){
        dictionaryFP = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
        hashedDictionaryFP = fopen("hashedDictionary.txt", "w");
        noOfWords = countWords(dictionaryFP);
        arrayLength = calculateArrayLength(noOfWords);
        dictionary = (char**) malloc (arrayLength * (sizeof(char*)));
        for (i=0;i<arrayLength;i++){
            dictionary[i] = NULL;
        }
        printf("dictionary.txt dosyasindaki kelimeler hash'lenip bellege kaydediliyor...\n\n");
        readDictionary(dictionaryFP, dictionary, arrayLength);
        printf("Hash'lenen kelimeler hashedDictionary.txt dosyasina yaziliyor...\n");
        printHashedDictionary(hashedDictionaryFP, dictionary, arrayLength);

        fclose(hashedDictionaryFP);
        fclose(dictionaryFP);
        for (i=0;i<arrayLength;i++){
            free(dictionary[i]);
        }
        free(dictionary);
        printf("Tum kelimeler hash'lendi ve hashedDictionary.txt dosyasina kaydedildi.\n");
    }

    hashedDictionaryFP = fopen("hashedDictionary.txt", "r");
    if (hashedDictionaryFP == NULL){
        printf("hashedDictionary.txt bulunamadi. Program kapatiliyor.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\nhashedDictionary.txt dosyasindaki hash'lenmis kelimeler ve indisleri bellege okunuyor...\n");
    fscanf(hashedDictionaryFP, "%d\n", &arrayLength);
    printf("Dizi uzunlugu: %d.\n", arrayLength);
    dictionary = (char**) malloc (arrayLength * (sizeof(char*)));
    readHashedDictionary(hashedDictionaryFP, dictionary, arrayLength);
    displayHashedDictionary(dictionary, arrayLength);
    printf("%s", dictionary[7740]);
    printf("LOL");
    return 0;
}

int countWords (FILE* fp){
    char word[WORD_LENGTH];
    int i = 0;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s\n", word) == 1){
        i++;
    }
    printf("\nToplam kelime sayisi: %d.\n", i);
    rewind(fp);
    return i;
}

int calculateArrayLength (int noOfWords){
    int i;
    int ok = 0;
    int arrayLength = 2 * noOfWords;
    printf("Kelime sayisinin iki kati: %d.\n", arrayLength);
    while (ok == 0){
        i = 2;
        while (i < arrayLength && (arrayLength % i != 0)){
            i++;
        }
        if (i == arrayLength){
            ok = 1;
        } else {
            arrayLength++;
        }
    }
    printf("Dizi uzunlugu: %d.\n\n", arrayLength);
    return arrayLength;
}

void readDictionary (FILE* dictionaryFP, char** dictionary, int arrayLength){
    char word[WORD_LENGTH];
    long index;
    while (fscanf(dictionaryFP, "%s", word) == 1){
        fixCapitalLetters(word);
        index = hash (dictionary, word, arrayLength);
        dictionary[index] = (char*) malloc (WORD_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(dictionary[index], word);
    }
}

void fixCapitalLetters (char* word){
    int i = 0;
    while (word[i] != '\0'){
        if (word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z'){
            word[i] += 32;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int hash (char** dictionary, char* word, int arrayLength){
    int index, i;
    for (i=index=0; i < strlen(word); i++){
        index += (word[i])* 26 *i ;
    }
    index = index % arrayLength;
    //printf("%s kelimesi icin bulunan ilk indis: %d.\n", word, index);
    while (dictionary[index] != NULL){
        //printf("%d. indiste %s oldugu icin %s buraya yerlesemez.\n", index, dictionary[index], word);
        index = (++index) % arrayLength;
        //printf("%s kelimesi icin belirlenen yeni indis: %d.\n", word, index);
    }
    return index;
}

void printHashedDictionary (FILE* hashedDictionaryFP, char** dictionary, int arrayLength){
    int i;
    fprintf(hashedDictionaryFP, "%d\n", arrayLength);
    for (i=0;i<arrayLength;i++){
        if (dictionary[i] != NULL){
            fprintf(hashedDictionaryFP, "%d: %s\n", i, dictionary[i]);
        }
    }
}

void readHashedDictionary (FILE* hashedDictionaryFP, char** dictionary, int arrayLength){
    char word[WORD_LENGTH];
    int index;
    dictionary = (char**) malloc ((arrayLength) * sizeof(char*));
    while (fscanf(hashedDictionaryFP, "%d: %s\n", &index, word) > 0){
        dictionary[index] = (char*) malloc (WORD_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(dictionary[index], word);
        printf("%d: %s\n", index, dictionary[index]);
    }
    printf("%s", dictionary[7740]);
    printf("Hash'lenmis kelimelerin tamami hashedDictionary.txt dosyasindan bellege alindi.\n");
}

void checkWord (char** dictionary, char* word, int arrayLength){
    int noOfTries = 1;
    int index, i;
    for (i=index=0; i < strlen(word); i++){
        index += (word[i])* 26 *i ;
    }
    index = index % arrayLength;
    printf("%s kelimesi icin bulunan ilk index: %d. Orada %s var.\n", word, index, dictionary[index]);
    while ((dictionary[index] != NULL) && (strcmp(dictionary[index], word) != 0) && (noOfTries < arrayLength)){
        printf("donguye girdik.\n");
        index = (++index) % arrayLength;
        noOfTries++;
    }
    printf("donguden ciktik.\n");
    if (dictionary[index] != NULL && noOfTries < arrayLength){
        printf("%d. indiste %s kelimesi bulundu.\n", index, dictionary[index]);
    } else {
        printf("%s kelimesi yok.\n", word);
    }
}

void displayHashedDictionary (char** dictionary, int arrayLength){
    int i;
    printf("\nSozluk:\n");
    for (i=0;i<arrayLength;i++){
        if (dictionary[i] != NULL){
            printf("%d: %s\n",i, dictionary[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should avoid forward declaring all of the variables like that. It's just extra clutter, better to just declare them at the place where you're defining  them

Comment: @Alexander that is a matter of choice. I like my variables in a group at the top.

Comment: @WeatherVane Actually, it used to be a matter of necessary, prior to C99. That's where the style originates from, and it's been antiqued ever since. It added lots of extra lines (clutter), and unnecessarily distances variable declarations from their use, which makes code changes involve much more scrolling and looking around than necessary

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to set `char **dictionary` in a function, you need yet another level of indirection:

- The parameter pointers to the address of the array pointer
- The array pointer points to the start of the buffer holding the char pointers
- The char pointers point to the start of the strings

Comment: Check out readDictionary function. I did exactly the same thing in readHashedDictionary function but readHashedDictionary doesn't affect the string array in the main function while readDictionary does.
Edit: Sorry, my bad. I didn't exactly do the same thing. Fixed it now. That being said, what you suggested was irrelevant.

Comment: @Görkem - No, Alexander is right. When you do `dictionary = (char**) malloc ((arrayLength) * sizeof(char*));` that only affects the local parameter and the variable in `main` is unaffected. Any other changes you do to `dictionary` after that also just works for the local object.

Comment: The problem was that I was declaring the whole dictionary in the function which was causing the program to get rid of previously declared dictionary of the main function. I didn't need another level of indirection. Or, I'm stuck in the language barrier here and can't quite get what Alexander told me. Anyway, I fixed the issue by removing the first memory allocation of the function.

Comment: @GörkemŞahin Well perhaps try to understand what I'm saying before declaring `what you suggested was irrelevant`. The `dictionary` local variable starts by pointing to a valid piece of memory, which you reassign to point to a new piece of memory, so all further operations in the function happen on this new memory, without effecting the original. One solution was what you did, and that was to allocate the dictionary before the function call, and then *not* allocating it again inside the function call.

Comment: @GörkemŞahin Another solution, the one I point of in this answer, is if you want the allocation to *not* happen before the function call, but rather inside it. That is, you call `f(..., &dictionaryPointer,...)` where the dictionaryPointer is not set before the call, but is set by `f` inside the call. This would require another level of indirection, so the type of the argument would be `char ***dictionary`.

Comment: when you put it like "you need yet another level of indirection" i thought what you meant was that i was supposed to use another pointer that points to the matrix, like a char*** so it was the language barrier indeed.

Comment: i see what you meant, but i don't need a char*** for a char matrix. why would you tell me to use another pointer when i could just delete a line from the function?

Comment: @GörkemŞahin Different perceptions of what you were trying to achieve. (Allocating memory inside the function, vs depending on the caller to pass in the pointer already allocated for you)